# Q: How to check the extension of an URL website?

Tags: php, url, get

I would like to know if there is a way to check the extension of an `URL` website ? For example, do something when the website is like `http://example.es/` and do another thing when the website is like `http://example.fr/`

I have check that there is something like

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

which returns the current URL of the web page.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I think this is what you want https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php and this https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [parse_url()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function to get host part of the url then explode by . and get last element of an array

Example below:

```
    $url =  'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; 
    echo end(explode(".", parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST))); 
    // echos "com"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that exactly what i need. I was trying with trim function to take only the end of the URL  but explode worked fine.

Comment: NOTICE Only variables should be passed by reference

Answer (score 1):

From your example I assume that you are using PHP, then you can use `parse_url` to get the components.
https://www.php.net/parse-url

For example you can get the `host` example.fr and example.com, then do `explode` on host string to get the tld, .fr or .com, which should help you to do further if-else.